# Hardware/BIOS - IBM x3200 m2

Tags: hardware, bios, ibm-xseries, display, jumpstart

When I turn on my machine, the display is not throwing any output to it.

The fans are running fine.

The LED lights indicate no error, '
Only two LED's are blinking "Mini-BMCheartbeat LED" and "Standby power LED" 
The article mentions about the error LED's

> http://www.manualslib.com/manual/419746/Ibm-436854u-System-X3200-M2-5u-Mini-Tower-Server.html?page=170

There are three jumpers(jp1,jp3,jp6) which are in the default locations

> http://www.manualslib.com/manual/419746/Ibm-436854u-System-X3200-M2-5u-Mini-Tower-Server.html?page=31

Further analysis showed me that, I have blowed the Motherboard BIOS, it needs to be re-flashed with new bios

Could anyone please assist me in fixing this and let me know if more information is required.

> Thanks, 
>   Teja

Answer (score 1):

Recovering from a BIOS update failure:

If power to the server is interrupted while BIOS code is being updated, the server might not restart correctly or might not display video.

If this happens, use the procedure in this section to recover the BIOS code.

To complete the procedures in this section, you must make the following
preparations:
 Download the BIOS code image to create the POST/BIOS recovery diskette, CD,
or DVD from http://www.ibm.com/systems/support/.

https://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-5073476#DOCPRODUCTS

To create and use a diskette, you must attach an optional external USB diskette
drive to the server. To enable the USB diskette drive, complete the following
steps:

1. Enable the USB Support option in the Devices and I/O Ports menu in the
   Configuration/Setup Utility program.
2. Set your removable media device as the first startup device.
3. Select the removable media device that you want to boot from and move it to
   the top of the list.

To recover the BIOS code, complete the following steps:

1.) Turn off the server and all attached devices; then, disconnect all power cords and external cables.

2.) Locate the boot block recovery jumper (JP6) on the system board  and remove any adapters that impede access to the jumper

3.) Move the boot block recovery jumper to pins 2 and

4.) Insert the update diskette, CD, or DVD into the diskette, CD, or DVD drive

5.) Turn on the server and the monitor.
After the update session is completed, remove the diskette, CD, or DVD from
the drive and turn off the server

6.) Disconnect all power cords and external cables

7.) Return the boot block recovery jumper to pins 1 and 2.

8.) Reconnect the external cables and power cords; then, turn on the attached
devices and turn on the server

Thank you..